# Xcode Firebase Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, segmentation-fault

I got this annoying error the other day. Segmentation fault: 11 was popping up in a random fashion on code that should work.

I googled a lot and with a bunch of different answers to the problem. What solved my issue with this error was to upgrade Firebase.

Open your terminal and go to your pod folder. Type 'pod update'. Let it do it's magic and reopen and build your project in Xcode.

This solved my segmentation issue. Hope it helps you out as well :)

Tommy

Comment: Sounds like you found how to solve your problem, which is great. And thanks for your willingness to share it. To make it fit here on Stack Overflow, it should be posted in a question-and-answer format. In the question, include the minimum steps that are needed to reproduce the problem and complete details on the error (including the exact error text, since segmentation faults are very common when developing for iOS). Without those, chances of anyone stuck in the same situation finding your post are minimal.